# CoreData crash after app update but SAME data model

Tags: ios, core-data, cocoapods, core-data-migration

```
***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'
```

I'm getting this crash, which normally occurs when updating the `xcdatamodel` and not migrating properly. However, I have not changed the data model at all, and I get this crash fairly often when updating my application through TestFlight. Has anyone seen this before or have any idea what is happening?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622056/coredata-crash-after-app-update) with an answer stating that clearing the `NSFetchedResultsController` cache can help with avoiding this crash but I do not use caching in my fetches.

**NOTE**: I use TestFlight to deploy my app and it crashes when updating through TestFlight (old style through the website, not iOS 8 style through iTunes Connect). I also use CocoaPods (I mention this because it has caused strange problems before). Could this be a problem with either of these tools?

**EDIT:** When I update the app, and this problem arises, I've noticed that my entire core data database gets deleted on update.

**EDIT 2:** When updating through TestFlight, the app appears as a new app (new icon) while downloading/installing, and once installed then new icon disappears and "merges" with the existing app icon.

Comment: You have to provide some code snippets for us to determine if you're properly performing a migration. To me, it sounds like there's a merge conflict and it's throwing away everything because there's no setting to handle conflicts. ... or it's just not being merged properly

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the problem myself, and it was CocoaPods related. I was clearing out my Pods-resources.sh file to fix a problem with .xcassets being duplicated because of a bug in CocoaPods. However, this also removed some .xcdatamodel files from being copied from one of my Pods, thus changing my data model, and crashing my application.

I should've been more careful clearing out that Pods-resources.sh file.